# Python - Replace() for a list of keywords

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, time, replace

I have a list of companies with their name + business acronym, for example:

```
['Abc Inc','def Gmbh','ghi PLC', 'xhlm SA', 'sojs LLC'] and so on.
```

I'd like to get a clean list without PLC, INC, Gmbh, and every acronym like those. For this reason, I added a for loop that goes through a list of acronym to remove and replace them from the company name with "".

That's what i came with, but increase terribly the time needed to process my code. Any better idea?

```
def ExtractNames():

substring_adjustment = ['AB', 'AB', 'B.V', 'B.v', 'BV', 'BV', 'GMBH', 'Gmbh', 'INC', 'INC.', 'Inc', 'Inc.', 'LTD', 'Ltd', 'NV', 'NV', 'P.L.C', 'P.L.C', 'PLC', 'Plc', 'SA', 'SE', 'SE', 'SPA', 'Sa', 'Spa', 'ab', 'b.v', 'bv', 'gmbh', 'inc', 'inc.', 'ltd', 'nv', 'p.l.c', 'plc', 'sa', 'se', 'spa',",",".","-"]  
Company_List= load_workbook(filename='Excel for Scraping.xlsx',data_only=True).active 

for row in Company_List.iter_rows (min_row=2,min_col=1,max_col=1,values_only=True): 
    value = row[0]
    for word in substr_adjust:
        value = value.replace(word,"")
        print(value)
```

Comment: @erip: That only works for replacing single characters with something else; the OP has multicharacter strings to replace.

Comment: You could use some sort of regular expression.

Comment: In the future in 3.9, you could use [`str.removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) to solve this problem. Probably won't be as fast as the regular-expression solutions however.

Comment: @HampusLarsson: Very nice suggestion! But this only works for fixed strings, doesn't it? Also isn't this just a wrapper around `endswith()` ?

Comment: @Jan You can read more about in in [PEP 616](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/). It's basically both an `endswith()` together with a index-slice of the given string. You're right that it would only really with fixed strings though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over all the substrings that *might* be present in the value (and then using `replace`, which has potential other issues e.g. if a word in the company name contains "ab" as a substring), you could make a set of substrings and loop over words in the company name, testing if they are listed, and join together (with space separator) those words which are not.  Set inclusion testing is O(1) time, so it should not be so slow.

```
substring_adjustment = {'AB', 'AB', 'B.V', 'B.v', 'BV', 'BV', 'GMBH', 'Gmbh', 'INC', 'INC.', 'Inc', 'Inc.', 'LTD', 'Ltd', 'NV', 'NV', 'P.L.C', 'P.L.C', 'PLC', 'Plc', 'SA', 'SE', 'SE', 'SPA', 'Sa', 'Spa', 'ab', 'b.v', 'bv', 'gmbh', 'inc', 'inc.', 'ltd', 'nv', 'p.l.c', 'plc', 'sa', 'se', 'spa',",",".","-"}


for value in ['Abc Inc','def Gmbh','ghi PLC', 'xhlm SA', 'sojs LLC']:

    print(' '.join(word for word in value.split()
                   if word not in substring_adjustment))
```

gives:

```
Abc
def
ghi
xhlm
sojs LLC
```

Note also that your expression for `substring_adjustment` in fact has some repeated items (e.g. `'AB'`, `'BV'`), but these will be automatically dealt with when you create the set.

Comment: It worked perfectly and cut my processing time by 20%. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could join your replacements and use a regular expression:

```
import re
substring_adjustment = ['AB', 'AB', 'B.V', 'B.v', 'BV', 'BV', 'GMBH', 'Gmbh', 'INC', 'INC.', 'Inc', 'Inc.', 'LTD', 'Ltd', 'NV', 'NV', 'P.L.C', 'P.L.C', 'PLC', 'Plc', 'SA', 'SE', 'SE', 'SPA', 'Sa', 'Spa', 'ab', 'b.v', 'bv', 'gmbh', 'inc', 'inc.', 'ltd', 'nv', 'p.l.c', 'plc', 'sa', 'se', 'spa',",",".","-"]
lst = ['Abc Inc','def Gmbh','ghi PLC', 'xhlm SA', 'sojs LLC']

rx = re.compile(r'\s*(?:{})$'.format("|".join(substring_adjustment)))

new_list = [rx.sub('', item) for item in lst]
print(new_list)
# ['Abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'xhlm', 'sojs LL']
```

As you can see, the problem with this approach is that you need to put the longer replacements first. Additionally, you have duplicates in your substitutions list.
That being said, you could change your replacements list and the regular expression to:

```
import re

substring_adjustment = ['AB', 'B\.?V', 'GMBH', 'INC\.?', 'LTD', 'NV', 'P\.?L\.?C', 'S[AE]', 'SPA']
lst = ['Abc Inc', 'def Gmbh', 'ghi PLC', 'xhlm SA', 'sojs LLC', 'XXX Management Limited']

rx = re.compile(r'(?i)\s*\b(?:{})$'.format("|".join(substring_adjustment)))

new_list = [rx.sub('', item) for item in lst]
print(new_list)
```

Which yields for your example:

```
['Abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'xhlm', 'sojs LLC', 'XXX Management Limited']
```

Comment: Thanks for this! 
I am going through the regex documentation to understand each of the character you put. While running the code i noticed one trouble:
it works perfectly for the companies with acronyms, but for companies without acronym in some cases it cuts the last letter, going to understand why.

XXX Management Limited -> XXX Management Limite
YYY Corporation -> YYY Corporatio
ZZZ Malaysia -> ZZZ Malaysi

Comment: @AdrianoPatruno: Take the second regex not the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it quicker than that, with regex:

```
import re

def ExtractNames():
    substring_adjustment = ['AB', 'AB', 'B.V', 'B.v', 'BV', 'BV', 'GMBH', 'Gmbh', 'INC', 'INC.', 'Inc', 'Inc.', 'LTD', 'Ltd', 'NV', 'NV', 'P.L.C', 'P.L.C', 'PLC', 'Plc', 'SA', 'SE', 'SE', 'SPA', 'Sa', 'Spa', 'ab', 'b.v', 'bv', 'gmbh', 'inc', 'inc.', 'ltd', 'nv', 'p.l.c', 'plc', 'sa', 'se', 'spa',",",".","-"]  
    removal_regex = '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in substring_adjustment)
    # 'AB|AB|B\\.V|B\\.v|BV|BV|...'
    for row in Company_List.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_col=1, values_only=True):
        value = re.sub(removal_regex, '', row[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you just replacing possible part of company name

```
company_name = "ABBA AB"
print(company_name.replace("AB", ""))
# 'BA '
```

Maybe you want to split your company_name string and than filter values separately

```
substring_adjustment_set = {'AB', 'B.V', 'B.v', 'BV', 'GMBH', 'Gmbh'}
string_list = company_name.split(" ")
result = " ".join(filter(lambda x: x not in substring_adjustment_set, string_list))
print(result) 
# ABBA
```